# Create a pixmap which is the difference of two shapes

Tags: libgdx

I'd like to create an overlay in my libGDX game to be used during onboarding. Basically I'd like to overlay the entire screen with a 40% alpha rectangle (that's easy) but I want a cutout of a circle on top of the area of interest where the user should focus attention. Is there a way to create a texture which is the difference of two shapes or pixmaps?

```
Pixmap overlay = new Pixmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
overlay.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0.4f);
overlay.fillRectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

Pixmap overlayCutout = new Pixmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
overlayCutout.setColor(Color.WHITE);
overlayCutout.fillCircle(focusAreaX, focusAreaY, radius);

Texture t = new Texture(overlay); 
//subtract overlayCutout??
overlay.dispose();
overlayCutout.dispose();

batch.draw(t);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely got what you want to do, but I think the trick is to use only one `Pixmap`...

```
Pixmap overlay = new Pixmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
overlay.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0.4f);
overlay.fillRectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

// the trick is to "redraw" the inner circle with an "invisible" colour alpha=0
overlay.setBlending(Blending.None);
overlay.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
overlay.fillCircle(focusAreaX, focusAreaY, radius);
overlay.setBlending(Blending.SourceOver);

Texture t = new Texture(overlay); 
overlay.dispose();

batch.draw(t);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @noone. Unfortunately, I tried this and the circle is indeed invisible -- there is no cutout at all, just a solid semi-transparent rectangle.

Comment: @rundavidrun I edited my answer. You have to set the blending mode to None so it will not be blended, but completely change the colour. After it you have to set it back to default.